# Reading file with delimiter and outputing in order

Tags: java

I have the following file fruit.txt below, I would like to read in the file and output them in order.

What i have done, is i try to use nested for loop to get the list but I failed.
I am unsure how to add in more record into the loop.

```
BufferedReader brInput = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fruit.txt"));
String line;
String x = null;
while ((line = brInput.readLine()) != null) {
   String[] fruit = line.split("\\.");

    for(int i =0; i<fruit.length;i++){
        for(int j =0; j<fruit.length;j++){
             x = fruit[i]+"."+fruit[j];
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

current output:

```
apple.apple
apple.orange
apple.pear
apple.grape
orange.apple
```

fruit.txt:

```
apple.orange.pear.grape
apple.orange.pear.grape.melon
apple.orange.pear.grape.melon.Apricot
banana.berry.Avocado
```

expected output:

```
apple
apple.orange
apple.orange.pear
apple.orange.pear.grape

apple
apple.orange
apple.orange.pear
apple.orange.pear.grape
apple.orange.pear.grape.melon

apple
apple.orange
apple.orange.pear
apple.orange.pear.grape
apple.orange.pear.grape.melon
apple.orange.pear.grape.melon.Apricot

banana
banana.berry
banana.berry.Avocado
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to iterate through the String array once. Assign the first value to your `String x`, then append each succeeding items in your array to `x`. You can modify your for loop, like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
  if(i == 0) {
    x = fruit[i];
  } else {
    x += "." + fruit[i];
  }
  System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: This is the accepted answer!? Use the approach Thomas suggested, far better for building strings like this

Answer (score 3):

What you're currently doing is combine each array element with each array element (even the same ones). It seems like you want to add one of the array elements in each iteration hence you should do it like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for( String word : fruit) {
  //if there's already something in the StringBuilder add a dot before adding the word
  if( sb.length() > 0 ) {
    sb.append( "." );
  }

  sb.append( word );
  System.out.println( sb.toString() );
}
```

Assuming the fruit array is `{"apple","orange","pear","grape"}` this would output

```
apple
apple.orange
apple.orange.pear    
apple.orange.pear.grape
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code with scanner library, this will work perfectly till end:

```
File f=new File("C:/Users/User1/Desktop/t.txt");

            Scanner s=new Scanner(f);
            s.useDelimiter("\r\n");
            String d=null;
            String temp=null;
            String da[]=null;

            int i=0;

            d=s.nextLine();

            while(s.hasNextLine()){                 
                d=d.replace(".", ",");
                da=null;
                da=d.split(",");

                temp=null;
                i=0;

                while(i<da.length){
                    if(i==0){
                        temp=da[i];
                    }
                    else{
                temp=temp+"."+da[i];    

                    }

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,temp);  //-----------Output-------------
                i++;
                }                   
                d=null;
                d=s.nextLine();
                }   
            s.close();
```